Flatpack Ubuntu 24.04 GPU drivers
I have this script that will help me to set up my Ubuntu:
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update -y

sudo apt upgrade -y

sudo apt install terminator -y

sudo apt install net-tools -y

sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system bridge-utils -y

sudo adduser alex libvirt

sudo adduser alex kvm

sudo apt install virt-manager -y

sudo apt install figlet -y

sudo apt install wireshark -y

sudo apt install gparted -y
sudo apt install flatpak -y
flatpak --user remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

flatpak update -y
flatpak install flathub com.discordapp.Discord
flatpak install flathub com.jgraph.drawio.desktop
flatpak install flathub org.videolan.VLC
flatpak install flathub us.zoom.Zoom
flatpak install flathub com.simplenote.Simplenote
flatpak install flathub org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent
sudo apt install nmap
flatpak install flathub com.getpostman.Postman
flatpak install flathub com.spotify.Client
git clone https://github.com/athityakumar/colorls.git

# clean
sudo find /var/ -size +10M -ls | sort -n -r -k 7

sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/syslog

sudo journalctl --disk-usage

sudo journalctl --rotate

sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=1s

sudo journalctl --rotate --vacuum-size=500M

sudo snap list --all | while read snapname ver rev trk pub notes; do if [[ $notes = *disabled* ]]; then snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$rev"; fi; done

print important and shutdown


read a

sudo ./see.sh

I created this script on Ubuntu 22.04, and now I installed Ubuntu 24.04 from scratch. I installed it multiple times because I had a bug. The os is working perfectly until I run this script. I did it in July when I thought the os was not entirely released. The bug was that when I left my PC for a while, it would be locked, and then if I made just one mistake in my password, it would have a lock screen and never come back. I have tried multiple things, but nothing worked; maybe it was something about the GPU. The flatpack, when it is updating, is updating the graphic drivers, and it is messing up with the GPU; this is my theory.
Do you have similar issues, or do you know if the flatpack for the new ubuntu has the updated drivers?
